# How to rotate MPMoviePlayerController video but not for its superview

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, video

My MPMoviePlayerController view is added as a subview to another view controller's view. When I play the video in full screen and flip the simulator, the video does not flip, nor does the parent view. However, when I add `return YES` to the rotation method (check codes below), the video rotates when it is in full screen as I wanted, but the parent view also rotates, which I don't want, because I did not design a landscape view for the parent view. How can I allow rotation ONLY for the video when it is in full screen and not the parent view??

Here are the codes I used:

For the video:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    NSBundle *bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"MainPageMovie" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *movieURL=[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake(115.0, 156.0, 200.0, 150.0);
    [self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
    [theMovie play];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];
}
```

And for the rotation method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to use MPMoviePlayerViewController to display the movie. Being a separate view controller, this should handle rotation for you.

If you really want to do it by adding an MPMoviePlayerController as a subview, you have a more difficult task ahead of you. Basically, you would have to listen for UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification and apply the appropriate `transform`, `bounds`, and `center` to the movie player view depending on the device's orientation.

Comment: So basically either I design a landscape view for the parent view which would make me design landscape views for the entire app or keep the video playing in portrait view huh?? :P Thanks anyway :) I'll try to add the video on a separate view. This should solve my problem :)